# Getting the output from a arraylist

Tags: java

Im fairly new to java and ive been doing som searching for an answer to my problem but i just cant seem to get the output from the arraylist. 
I get a red mark under Ordtildikt `String arrayoutput = kontrollObjekt.Ordtildikt;`saying it cannot be resolved or is not a field. The program is supposed to get userinput and create an arraylist from the input

**Interface class**

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Grensesnitt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Grensesnitt Grensesnitt = new Grensesnitt();
        Grensesnitt.meny();     
    }

    Kontroll kontrollObjekt = new Kontroll();
    private final String[] ALTERNATIVER = {"Registrere ord","Skriv dikt","Avslutt"};
    private final int REG = 0;
    private final int SKRIV = 1;

    public void meny() {
        boolean fortsett = true;
        while(fortsett) {
            int valg = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
                    null, 
                    "Gjør et valg:", 
                    "Prosjektmeny", 
                    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,  
                    null, 
                    ALTERNATIVER, 
                    ALTERNATIVER[0]); 
            switch(valg) {
            case REG: regNy();
                break;
            case SKRIV: regDikt();
                break;
            default: fortsett = false;
            }
        } 
    }

    int i = 0;

    public void regNy() { 
        while(i<=16)
        {
            String Ord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Skriv or til diktet: ");
            kontrollObjekt.regNy(Ord);

        //String Diktord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Skriv ord til diktet: ");
        //kontrollObjekt.regNy(Diktord);
        i = i + 1;  
        }
    }

    public void regDikt() {
        String arrayoutput = kontrollObjekt.Ordtildikt;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, arrayoutput);

            }
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, kontrollObjekt.Diktord);
    }
```

**Controll Class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Kontroll {
public ArrayList<String> Diktord = new ArrayList<String>();

public void regNy(String Ord) {
    Diktord.add(Ord);
    Diktord.add("\n");

    }
public String Ordtildikt(String Ord) {
    return Ord=Diktord.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: ah its supposed to say `String arrayoutput = kontrollObjekt.Ordtildikt;` instead. edited now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a method, not a variable.

```
kontrollObjekt.Ordtildikt;
```

You are trying to call this?

```
public String Ordtildikt(String Ord) {
    return Ord=Diktord.toString();
}
```

1) Make it `return Diktord.toString();`

2) Get rid of `String Ord` unless you are going to use that parameter

3) Actually call the method, e.g. Put some parenthesis.

```
String arrayoutput = kontrollObjekt.Ordtildikt();
```

Also, I think this should be the correct `regNy` method unless you want to falsely report that the list is twice its size.

```
public void regNy(String Ord) {
    Diktord.add(Ord + "\n");
}
```